# How can I pass state variable as param for route specified in CommonActions.reset()?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I suspect `navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.reset())` is reseting the state before they can be passed as params.

---

**Here is my setup:**

I have defined a state variable like:

```
const [quizID, setQuizID] = useState<string>("");
```

And I have a button that resets the navigation stack like:

```
<Button onPress={() => {
     console.log(quizID)
     navigation.dispatch(
         CommonActions.reset({
           index: 1,
           routes: [
           { name: 'HomeScreenWithDrawer' },
           {
              name: 'Quiz',
              params: {quizID: quizID},
           }],
         })
      );
 }}/>
```

This outputs to the console `<empty string>`. It seems that quizID is getting reset just from including the dispatch code, like it is being reset before the dispatch is called, meaning the quizID cannot be passed as a parameter.

I tested it by only changing the code by removing the reset/dispatch part like:

```
<Button onPress={() => {
     console.log(quizID)
 }}/>
```

And it outputs the correct quizID.

---

So why is this happening, and how can I pass state variable as param for route specified in CommonActions.reset()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer in case problem/solution generalizes past specific usage here and might help others (since reason is still unknown to me).

---

**This way of passing a state variable into a reset route param should work without issues (tested and confirmed).**

The problem was something to do with ProgressSteps from `@joaosousa/react-native-progress-steps` package. I had my dispatch code nested within one of the steps, which doesn't work for some unknown reason.

As a workaround, set an effect hook on some state variable like:

```
  const [viewQuiz, setViewQuiz] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    if(viewQuiz)
    {
      navigation.dispatch( (state: any) => {
          return CommonActions.reset({
            index: 1,
            routes: [
              { name: 'HomeScreenWithDrawer' },
              {
                name: 'Quiz',
                params: {quizID: quizID},
              },
            ],
          })
        }
      );
    }
  }, [viewQuiz]);
```

And within the step component, call `setViewQuiz(true);`